# Converter objeto json para objeto Delphi

Tags: delphi-xe5

Amigo como faço para transformar este objeto json para o delphi.

```
{
  "plates_ocr": [
    {
      "bottom_right": {
        "x": 167.14285714285717,
        "y": 115.71428571428572
      },
      "ocr": [
        {
          "confidence": 99.99907684326172,
          "text": "ABC1234"
        }
      ],
      "top_left": {
        "x": 57.142857142857146,
        "y": 68.57142857142857
      },
      "type": "car"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Não consigo responder, mas pesquise sobre SuperObject, e olhe esse [git](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject)  boa sorte